# Когда высвобождается память связанная с объектом PHP

Tags: php

```
for ($i=1; $i<99999; $i++){
  $ob = new BigObject();
}
```

Создаем объект конструктором и присваиваем ссылку на него переменной $ob. Затем, еще раз создаем объект и присваиваем ссылку на него той же переменной. Память выделенная для предыдущего объекта высвобождается сразу или только по окончании работы php-скрипта?

Comment: а самому посмотреть не судьба?

Answer (score 0):

Память освобождается сразу, как только у объекта не остается ссылок ведущих на него.

Подробнее на тему работы сборщика мусора в PHP, можно почитать в официальной документации: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php